# Google Analytics Experiments

Tags: google-analytics, google-experiments

I am running an experiment in GA for the last 6 days but although the experiment validates with no errors and we can see the variations using different browers.

However, after 6 days of testing, there are still no results in Experiments.

When i check the experiment, i get the following warnings:
Note: Three experiment variations do not appear in the table. The following 3 experiment variations have had no sessions.﻿

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a problem with the code in the page.
Make sure you followed the step 3 (Add the experiment code to your original page): https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1745152?hl=en